# How to DISABLE a device in c#.net

Tags: c#, windows, usb

I created windows application in c#.net.by this I disable usb Port in windows and I want To give access to usb devices to connect to windows So the other devices ingores by windows .How can I do this in c#.net

```
 // disable USB storage...             
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", "Start", 4, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                MessageBox.Show("Disabled");

       //enable USB storage...
                Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", "Start", 3, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                MessageBox.Show("Enabled");
```

for example I add each usb deivce I want into a list after that these devices added can be detected by windows

Comment: If it is disabled by policy, it will be disabled again once you machine restarts.

Comment: Dear Anand .I use this application as a winservice